# Mongoose populate returns different number of documents with find vs findById

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now. Mongoose `.populate` returns different amount of documents if I search with `.find` or `.findById` query, even tho the population configuration is exactly the same.

I'm using `mongoose": ^6.8.4`.

I have a `NewsSubCategory` Schema:

```
const NewsSubCategorySchema = new Schema<NewsSubCategoryInterface>(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
   
    articles: {
      data: [
        {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "NewsArticle"
        }
      ]
    }
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

As you can see, the schema have an array of `NewsArticle` in `articles.data` field.

So, when I try to execute the following query:

```
const subCategoriesData = await NewsSubCategory.find({
      _id: { $in: subCategories.data }
    })
      .limit(subCategoriesLimit)
      .skip(subCategoriesPage * subCategoriesLimit - subCategoriesLimit)
      .sort({ updatedAt: -1 })
      .populate<{
        articles: {
          data: NewsArticleInterface[];
        };
      }>({
        path: "articles.data",
        select:
          "some.fields.select",
        populate: {
          path: "fields.populate",
          select: "these fields to populate"
        },
        match: {
          "relationships.newsAgency.type": { $in: agenciesTypes.data },
          "relationships.newsAgency.country": { $in: agenciesCountries.data }
        },
        options: {
          sort: { createdAt: -1 },
          limit: newsArticleLimit,
          skip: newsArticlePage * newsArticleLimit - newsArticleLimit
        }
      })
```

I get very inconsistent results.

For example, if the `newsArticleLimit` is 10, some subcategories will get 10 articles in their `articles.data` field, and some not.

But then, if I run the following query to try to find the subcategory that just had less than 10 articles in `articles.data` field:

```
 let subCategoriesData = await NewsSubCategory.findById(id)
      .populate<{
        articles: {
          data: NewsArticleInterface[];
        };
      }>({
        path: "articles.data",
        select:
          "some.fields.select",
        populate: {
          path: "fields.populate",
          select: "these fields to populate"
        },
        match: {
          "relationships.newsAgency.type": { $in: agenciesTypes.data },
          "relationships.newsAgency.country": { $in: agenciesCountries.data }
        },
        options: {
          sort: { createdAt: -1 },
          limit: newsArticleLimit,
          skip: newsArticlePage * newsArticleLimit - newsArticleLimit
        }
      })
```

I would get the correct result, with 10 articles in the `articles.data` field, even though the populate is exactly the same.

So I get different result in populated fields depending on if I search for multiple subcategories using `find`, or for only one using `findById`.

Is there some explanation behind this behaviour and what can be the solution?

WHAT HAVE I TRIED SO FAR:

I have tried to change the `newsArticleLimit`, tried 10, 5, 50, 100, the amount of documents that are returned in the populated `articles.data` were always inconsistent.

I've checked my database RAM and CPU usage and there is no spikes when I execute the query.

I have tried to fetch all the subcategories first, then loop over them and individually fetch and populate them, that worked fine as expected. But that query takes more than 30 seconds to execute, and it's won't be good for production.

From the populate configuration, I have tried to remove every field, `match`, `select`, `populate`, `sort`, `skip`, but nothing works. The only thing that "worked" when I removed the `limit`, but then the query took very long time to execute, if I try to get more than one subcategory.

EDIT: "I have tried to change the `newsArticleLimit`..." instead of "I have tried to change the `newsAgencyLimit`..."

SOLUTION: The problem was solve using `perDocumentLimit` instead of `limit` in the population query options.

```
     options: {
      sort: { createdAt: -1 },
      perDocumentLimit: newsArticleLimit,
      skip: newsArticlePage * newsArticleLimit - newsArticleLimit
    }
```

Comment: What is `newsAgencyLimit`? I see it in the "what I have tried" paragraph but don't see any references to it in the query code

Comment: I'll also hazard a bit of a guess in the absence of more troubleshooting details - are you perhaps expecting the behavior provided by `perDocumentLimit` rather than `limit`?  The docs on the topic are [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#limit-vs-perDocumentLimit)

Comment: @user20042973 I fixed it by using `perDocumentLimit` instead of limit. Thank you for the suggestion, I haven't stumble across it before, even though I'm using `limit`  in populating options in many occasions in my code.